# Can an interceptor call business layer in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm using Spring MVC 3 for the current project and I want to make sure if an interceptor can call methods of the business layer to get data from design point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can access technically in spring, classic case can be menu handler as asked in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102153/what-is-the-idea-for-creating-a-menu-system-in-spring-mvc-application)