# What is the idea for creating a menu system in Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring-mvc, menuitem

We need a menu system in our application and we are using Spring MVC 3. 
The menu will be displayed on every page and and the menu items are stored in the database. What is the idea to bring the menu items back to the presentation layer when handling the requests?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using Sitemesh? It can do this sort of thing, take a look at these slides from Atlassian: http://www.slideshare.net/guest9fefea/sitemesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use sitemesh (any templating engine may be tiles) in conjunction with HandlerInterceptorAdapter. Below is sample code,

```
@Component
public class MenuHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Autowired
private MenuService menuService;

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
     load and set menu items in request attributes (session can also be used). 
    }
}
```

and use request/session attribute to common menu jsp.

Comment: i think no, if you are updating data then thread synchronization should be managed.

Comment: How should I put the synchronization code, a block in postHandle(...) method?